# What is the deep meaning of this quote given by Kabir?

Tags: meaning

All know that the drop merges into the ocean, but few know that the ocean merges into the drop by kabir

actually  im not getting this  quote .What is  the deep meaning of this quote

Comment: He is speaking about his inner bliss experience, in first part drops merging I to ocean refers to moksha ocean  coming to dro is inner bliss

Comment: Infinite emerges from finite. Thats why Upanishads mention the desire of Brahman(meaning expansion), 'Eko ham, bahu syam, I am one, let me be many' and Puranas personify Brahman as Brahma and creating mankind, saptrishi, gods and realms in nothingness. Thats why Yashoda saw entire cosmos in the mouth of Krishna, who was a top class yogi/Brahmgyani and reincarnation of sage Nara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deep meaning is explicit if you know the “Poornamdah” sloka

Om Puurnnam-Adah Puurnnam-Idam Puurnnaat-Purnnam-Udacyate
Puurnnashya Puurnnam-Aadaaya Puurnnam-Eva-Avashissyate ||
Om Shaantih Shaantih Shaantih ||

Meaning:
Aum! That is infinite, and this (universe) is infinite.
The infinite proceeds from the infinite.
(Then) taking the infinitude of the infinite (universe),
It remains as the infinite alone.
Aum! Peace! Peace! Peace!

Infinite fits in a drop as well.
Ocean is an allegory to the infinite.
Drop to infinitesimal.
You can shrink and fit the infinite in an infinitesimal is what Kabir is referring to. Science is close behind. The earth for e.g can fit in a marble in a blackhole.